# django-autocomplete-light simple usage

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

I am trying to understand how to use [django-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light) for an existing project. This seems like a good autocomplete solution for django for which I am already using normal ModelChoiceFields.

So, let's say that I have a Model named MyModel that has an id and a name. What I'd like to know is the simplest possible way of creating a form widget that would provide me the same functionality with

```
mymodel = forms.ModelChoiceField(  required=True, queryset=ships.models.Authority.objects.all() , )
```

so I'd be able to add that widget to any form I wanted in order to select instances of MyModel without using selec.t

What are the required steps to have that ? I've already added 'autocomplete_light' to INSTALLED_APPS and

```
url(r'autocomplete/', include('autocomplete_light.urls')),
```

to urls.py and

```
import autocomplete_light
autocomplete_light.autodiscover()
```

before

```
admin.autodiscover()
```

however I am getting confused with what to do next :(

Please don't point me in the documentation I've already read it thoroughly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Select widget is default for ModelChoiceField

This form field does not specify a widget, so [the select widget should be used by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) with:

```
mymodel = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                required=True,
                queryset=ships.models.Authority.objects.all(),
          )
```

This is why you see a select field instead of an autocomplete.

Did you read [django docs about using widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) ?

### Use autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget instead

All you have to do is [specify the widget](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html#widget-in-action):

```
mymodel = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            required=True,
            queryset=ships.models.Authority.objects.all(),
            widget=autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('AutocompleteName')
          )
```

If you don't know what is the name of the autocomplete, login as staff and open `http://yoursite/autocomplete/`.

Ensure that you have jquery properly loaded and that autocomplete-light's staticfiles are loaded too !

### Alternatives

FTR: another way is possible, using `autocomplete_light.modelform_factory` using [shortcuts like `autocomplete_light.modelform_factory` or `autocomplete_light.get_widgets_dict`](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quick.html#quick-form-integration). [API docs](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html#id1) are passable but it does not beat [reading the source code](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/autocomplete_light/forms.py).

All in all, I think the easiest for you is using the get_widgets_dict shortcut **if you are using a ModelForm**.

### Hidden docs

You might not have found [the cookbook](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/docs_rewrite/cookbook.html#high-level-basics) because it is a work in progress in the docs_rewrite branch, but the second part of "High level basics" provides several examples of using the widget.

I know that the docs have a problem, hence the docs_rewrite branch. Right now I'm focusing on improving mobile support.

Comment: Thanks a lot this works with the addition of adding 
autocomplete_light.register(MyModel) !

Comment: Well I now have another question: How can I change the queryset based on the request ? I have different types of users that need to see different subsets of MyModel. Is it possible ?

Comment: Just override [choices_for_request](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html#autocomplete_light.autocomplete.base.AutocompleteBase.choices_for_request).

Comment: @Serafeim where did you add that `autocomplete_light.register(MyModel) ` I've been peppering my code with that and I can't find where it should go!

Comment: Please check the tutorial. You need to put it on autocomplete_light_registry.py!